# Give a consuming service a data context for the duration of the request?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

Tipically my application's EF model is consumed by the website itself, so I use the following extension method to grant a context for the duration of the request:

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    internal const string _contextDataKey = "dataContext";

    public static EntityDataModelContext GetDataContext(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null) // services
            return new EntityDataModelContext();

        if (httpContext.Items[_contextDataKey] == null)
            httpContext.Items.Add(_contextDataKey, new EntityDataModelContext());

        return (EntityDataModelContext)httpContext.Items[_contextDataKey];
    }
}
```

When a newly created WCF service attempted to get a data context, I stumbled upon the fact that a service holds no `HttpContext` in my application.

Now the solution I provided here "works", but I'd rather have a similar solution to what was done with the `HttpContext`.

Where can I store a data context for a service request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `IExtension` implementation for `OperationContext`. [Here is some example](http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/17/abstracting-request-state/) how to do that.